# SAPUI5 FIORI launchpad customIcon on BusyDialog is not working

Tags: mobile, sapui5, animated-gif

I am tring to add animation to a busyDialog , i can see it well in my development environment but not on FIORI launchpad.
see attached code.

can anyone think why it's not working?
Thanks!

```
sap.ui.getCore().AppContext._oWaitDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog({
                    // text: "Please wait...",
                    customIcon: "images/LogoLoader_WhiteCircle.gif",
                    customIconRotationSpeed:0
                });
                sap.ui.getCore().AppContext._oWaitDialog.open();
```

Comment: updating the resource in the server would help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include this folder in component.js file, component.js initializes all these folders when app run from Launchpad.`return UIComponent.extend("com.yourapp.namspace.Component", {
        metadata : {
            manifest: "json",   /* if you using manifest json file */
            includes: ["css/style.css", "images/LogoLoader_WhiteCircle.gif"]  /* all folders file that need to be accessed in app, css in case custom css*/
        },`

Answer (score -1):

I would say you are trying to get UI5 source of an old or local source in index.html
Try

```html
src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.50.6/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
```

Comment: The above source will not load in Firoi launchpad..In Firori launchpad app is initialises from component,js